# Calculating percentile of dataset column

Tags: r, statistics, percentile

A quick one for you, dearest R gurus:

I'm doing an assignment and I've been asked, in this exercise, to get basic statistics out of the `infert` dataset (it's in-built), and specifically one of its columns, `infert$age`.

For anyone not familiar with the dataset:

```
> table_ages     # Which is just subset(infert, select=c("age"));
    age
1    26
2    42
3    39
4    34
5    35
6    36
7    23
8    32
9    21
10   28
11   29
...
246  35
247  29
248  23
```

I've had to find median values of the column, variance, skewness, standard deviation which were all okay, until I was asked to **find the column "percentiles"**.

I haven't been able to find anything so far, and maybe I've translated it incorrectly from greek, the language of the assignment. It was "ποσοστημόρια", Google Translate pointed the English term to be "percentiles".

Any tutorials or ideas on finding those "percentiles" of `infert$age`?

Comment: See `?quantile` perhaps?

Comment: @AnandaMahto This looks basic enough to match the feel of the rest of the exercises. I think that was it.

You just nudged me into the solution, thanks :p

Answer (score 75, accepted):

If you order a vector `x`, and find the values that is half way through the vector, you just found a median, or 50th percentile. Same logic applies for any percentage. Here are two examples.

```
x <- rnorm(100)
quantile(x, probs = c(0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1)) # quartile
quantile(x, probs = seq(0, 1, by= 0.1)) # decile
```

Answer (score 39):

The `quantile()` function will do much of what you probably want, but since the question was ambiguous, I will provide an alternate answer that does something slightly different from `quantile()`.

```
ecdf(infert$age)(infert$age)
```

will generate a vector of the same length as `infert$age` giving the proportion of `infert$age` that is below each observation. You can read the `ecdf` documentation, but the basic idea is that `ecdf()` will give you a function that returns the empirical cumulative distribution. Thus `ecdf(X)(Y)` is the value of the cumulative distribution of X at the points in Y. If you wanted to know just the probability of being below 30 (thus what percentile 30 is in the sample), you could say

```
ecdf(infert$age)(30)
```

The main difference between this approach and using the `quantile()` function is that `quantile()` requires that you put in the probabilities to get out the levels, and this requires that you put in the levels to get out the probabilities.

Answer (score 23):

Using {dplyr}:

```
library(dplyr)

# percentiles
infert %>% 
  mutate(PCT = ntile(age, 100))

# quartiles
infert %>% 
  mutate(PCT = ntile(age, 4))

# deciles
infert %>% 
  mutate(PCT = ntile(age, 10))
```

Answer (score 7):

```
table_ages <- subset(infert, select=c("age"))
summary(table_ages)
#            age       
#  Min.   :21.00  
#  1st Qu.:28.00  
#  Median :31.00  
#  Mean   :31.50  
#  3rd Qu.:35.25  
#  Max.   :44.00
```

This is probably what they're looking for. `summary(...)` applied to a numeric returns the min, max, mean, median, and 25th and 75th percentile of the data.

Note that

```
summary(infert$age)
#    Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
#   21.00   28.00   31.00   31.50   35.25   44.00
```

The numbers are the same but the format is different. This is because `table_ages` is a data frame with one column (ages), whereas `infert$age` is a numeric vector. Try typing `summary(infert)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the hmisc package that will give you the following percentiles:

0.05, 0.1, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 0.9 , 0.95

Just use the describe(table_ages)