# Calculate a percentile of dataframe column efficiently

Tags: r, dataframe, quantile, ecdf

This question is an extension to the StackOverflow question asked and answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21219447/calculating-percentile-of-dataset-column).

My circumstances are different in that I want to calculate the percentile of each value within a vector of 50,000 (or more!) values. For example --

```
df <- data.frame(val = rnorm(n = 50000, mean = 50, sd = 20))
df$val.percentile <- sapply(X = df$val, function(x) ecdf(df$val)(x))
head(df)
```

Is there a good way to optimize the process for calculating the percentile for each value? Essentially I'd like to make it as efficient as possible so the run time is as small as possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can implement `dplyr::percent_rank()` to rank each value based on the percentile. This is different, however, from determining the rank based on a cumulative distribution function `dplyr::cume_dist()` (Proportion of all values less than or equal to the current rank).

Reproducible example:

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(val = rnorm(n = 1000000, mean = 50, sd = 20))
```

Show that `percent_rank()` differs from `cume_dist()` and that `cume_dist()` is the same as `ecdf(x)(x)`:

```
library(tidyverse)

head(df) %>% 
  mutate(pr  = percent_rank(val), 
         cd  = ecdf(val)(val), 
         cd2 = cume_dist(val))

       val  pr        cd       cd2
1 37.47092 0.4 0.5000000 0.5000000
2 53.67287 0.6 0.6666667 0.6666667
3 33.28743 0.0 0.1666667 0.1666667
4 81.90562 1.0 1.0000000 1.0000000
5 56.59016 0.8 0.8333333 0.8333333
6 33.59063 0.2 0.3333333 0.3333333
```

Speed of each approach for this example dataset is roughly similar, not exceeding a factor of 2:

```
library(microbenchmark)
mbm <- microbenchmark(
    pr_dplyr = mutate(df, pr = percent_rank(val)),
    cd_dplyr = mutate(df, pr = percent_rank(val)),
    cd_base  = mutate(df, pr = ecdf(val)(val)),
    times = 20
)

autoplot(mbm)
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

`ecdf` is already vectorized, there is no reason to use an `apply` function. You can simply run:

```
df$val.percentile <- ecdf(df$val)(df$val)
```

Comment: How was this answer any different than mine?

Comment: @42- It isn't, but you and Barker posted at almost the same time (with Barker being the first)

Comment: Huh, didn't see it when I was posting (or doing my editing). I was assuming it came later.