# Handling NAs when mapping several dataframe columns into their percentile values in R

Tags: r, dplyr, data-manipulation

```
> dput(zed)
    structure(list(col1 = c(0, 0.236258076229343, 0.43840483531742, 
    0, NaN, 0.198838380845137, 0.0754815882584196, 0.10176020461209, 
    0.045933014354067, 0.256237616143739, 0.0880658828009711, 0.117285153415946, 
    0.127902400629673, 0, 0.117682083253069, 0.114542851298834, 0.0584035686594367, 
    0.123456790123457, 0.196817420435511, 0.0369541251378046), col2 = c(0.121951219512195, 
    0.17979731938542, 0.305944055944056, 0, NaN, 0.239463601532567, 
    0.0625521267723103, 0.161729656111679, 0.0612745098039216, 0.22002200220022, 
    0.135608048993876, NaN, 0, 0, 0.0934420659191301, 0.140091696383087, 
    0.141872719902716, 0, 0.176720075400566, 0.253924284395199), 
        col3 = c(0.227540305157712, 0.264931804641559, 0.190018713264226, 
        0.564015792442188, NaN, 0.116857208286359, 0.136034761917893, 
        0.137370134394451, 0.227357158778513, 0.215714919326088, 
        0.240671647524362, 0.107512520868114, 0.0681162324911809, 
        0.195274360476469, NaN, 0.208033156719459, 0.199848016844409, 
        0.140383517621937, 0.202430694674985, 0.0927417625979096)), row.names = c(NA, 
    -20L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

> zed
# A tibble: 20 x 3
       col1     col2     col3
      <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
 1   0        0.122    0.228 
 2   0.236    0.180    0.265 
 3   0.438    0.306    0.190 
 4   0        0        0.564 
 5 NaN      NaN      NaN     
 6   0.199    0.239    0.117 
 7   0.0755   0.0626   0.136 
 8   0.102    0.162    0.137 
 9   0.0459   0.0613   0.227 
10   0.256    0.220    0.216 
11   0.0881   0.136    0.241 
12   0.117  NaN        0.108 
13   0.128    0        0.0681
14   0        0        0.195 
15   0.118    0.0934 NaN     
16   0.115    0.140    0.208 
17   0.0584   0.142    0.200 
18   0.123    0        0.140 
19   0.197    0.177    0.202 
20   0.0370   0.254    0.0927
```

I have the following dataframe, which has multiple columns `(col1, col2, col3)` for which I need to convert into percentiles (rounded to the nearest integer, so one of 1:100). My preference - and what I assume is easiest - is to add 3 additional columns `col1pctile, col2pctile, col3pctile` that maps each respective column to their percentile value (within that column).

Using the `fmsb::percentile()` function on a single column returns an error due to the presence of NAs.

```
> fmsb::percentile(zed$col1)
Error in quantile.default(dat, probs = seq(0, 1, by = 0.01), type = 7) : 
  missing values and NaN's not allowed if 'na.rm' is FALSE
```

Although the example dataframe above only has 20 rows, my actual dataframe is many more rows than just 20, and having percentile values actually makes sense for my use-case (whereas percentiles wouldn't make sense for only 20 rows).

I will edit this post shortly with my current attempts, which aren't working as I'd hope. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You could probably take advantage of something like `is.finite()` to subset only the finite values in each column, OR follow some of the advice here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21219447/calculating-percentile-of-dataset-column

Comment: So what do you want to do with `NaN` values ? Ignore them from calculation? and return 0 for their corresponding percentile value or keep them as it is?

Comment: @RonakShah preferably they have an NaN percentile value, so ignored from calculation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two challenges when using the `percentile` function from the `fmsb`. First, it cannot handle missing values. Second, it cannot handle zero.

Here is the code of the percentile function.

```
library(dplyr)
library(fmsb)

percentile
# function (dat) 
# {
#   pt1 <- quantile(dat, probs = seq(0, 1, by = 0.01), type = 7)
#   pt2 <- unique(as.data.frame(pt1), fromLast = TRUE)
#   pt3 <- rownames(pt2)
#   pt4 <- as.integer(strsplit(pt3, "%"))
#   datp <- pt4[as.integer(cut(dat, c(0, pt2$pt1), labels = 1:length(pt3)))]
#   return(datp)
# }
# <bytecode: 0x0000000016c498b0>
#   <environment: namespace:fmsb>
```

As you can see, there are no ways to specify the `na.rm` argument to the `quantile` function. However, simply set `na.rm = TRUE` to `quantile` function will not work because we would like the function to return `NA` when the input numbers are `NA`.

In addition, when providing a vector with zero, the function returns error as follows.

```
percentile(0:5)
# Error in cut.default(dat, c(0, pt2$pt1), labels = 1:length(pt3)) : 
#  'breaks' are not unique
```

My suggestion is to re-write the function to be able to return `NA` for `NA` input values, and add a small numbers for zero. Here is my modification for the function. I called it `percentile_narm_zero`.

```
percentile_narm_zero <- function(dat, small = 0.0000000000001){

  # Create a data frame with the numeric values and index
  dat2 <- data.frame(index = 1:length(dat), dat = dat)
  # Remove NA
  dat3 <- dat2[ !is.na(dat2$dat), ]
  # Add a small number to 0
  dat3$dat <- ifelse(dat3$dat == 0, dat3$dat + small, dat3$dat)

  # This part is the same as the percentile function
  pt1 <- quantile(dat3$dat, probs = seq(0, 1, by = 0.01), type = 7)
  pt2 <- unique(as.data.frame(pt1), fromLast = TRUE)
  pt3 <- rownames(pt2)
  pt4 <- as.integer(strsplit(pt3, "%"))
  datp <- pt4[as.integer(cut(dat3$dat, c(0, pt2$pt1)), labels = 1:length(pt3))]

  # Merge datp back to dat2
  dat3$datp <- datp
  dat4 <- merge(dat2, dat3, by = "index", all = TRUE)

  return(dat4$datp)
}
```

Now we can apply this function to all columns in `zed` using `mutate_all`.

```
zed2 <- zed %>% mutate_all(funs(pctile = percentile_narm_zero(.)))
# A tibble: 20 x 6
#       col1     col2     col3 col1_pctile col2_pctile col3_pctile
#      <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>       <int>       <int>       <int>
#  1   0        0.122    0.228           11          42          83
#  2   0.236    0.180    0.265           89          77          95
#  3   0.438    0.306    0.190          100         100          42
#  4   0        0        0.564           11          17         100
#  5 NaN      NaN      NaN               NA          NA          NA
#  6   0.199    0.239    0.117           84          89          18
#  7   0.0755   0.0626   0.136           34          30          24
#  8   0.102    0.162    0.137           45          65          30
#  9   0.0459   0.0613   0.227           23          24          77
# 10   0.256    0.220    0.216           95          83          71
# 11   0.0881   0.136    0.241           39          48          89
# 12   0.117  NaN        0.108           56          NA          12
# 13   0.128    0        0.0681          73          17           0
# 14   0        0        0.195           11          17          48
# 15   0.118    0.0934 NaN               62          36          NA
# 16   0.115    0.140    0.208           50          53          65
# 17   0.0584   0.142    0.200           28          59          53
# 18   0.123    0        0.140           67          17          36
# 19   0.197    0.177    0.202           78          71          59
# 20   0.0370   0.254    0.0927          17          95           6
```

Comment: wonderful. i did realize that `percentile()` did not handle zeros and so i was already (in another example) adding 0.1 to all values in the column. This is a great answer, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First define a function to calculate percentile group as:

```
percentile_group <- function(x)
{
  y <- as.numeric(x) %>% discard(is.na)
  qn <- quantile(y, probs = seq(0, 1, by= 0.1), na.rm = TRUE) %>% unique()
  grp <- cut(x, breaks=qn, include.lowest=T, labels=F)
  #return(qn)
  return(grp)
}
```

Now use the function in a mutate statement as

```
 mutate_if(zen, is.numeric, funs(pctile = percentile_group))
```

The output is:

```
# A tibble: 20 x 6
col1     col2     col3 col1_pctile col2_pctile col3_pctile
<dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>       <int>       <int>       <int>
  1   0        0.122    0.228            1           4           9
2   0.236    0.180    0.265            8           7          10
3   0.438    0.306    0.190            9           9           5
4   0        0        0.564            1           1          10
5 NaN      NaN      NaN               NA          NA          NA
6   0.199    0.239    0.117            8           8           2
7   0.0755   0.0626   0.136            3           2           3
8   0.102    0.162    0.137            4           6           3
9   0.0459   0.0613   0.227            2           2           8
10   0.256    0.220    0.216            9           8           8
11   0.0881   0.136    0.241            3           4           9
12   0.117  NaN        0.108            5          NA           2
13   0.128    0        0.0681           7           1           1
14   0        0        0.195            1           1           5
15   0.118    0.0934 NaN                6           3          NA
16   0.115    0.140    0.208            4           5           7
17   0.0584   0.142    0.200            2           5           6
18   0.123    0        0.140            6           1           4
19   0.197    0.177    0.202            7           7           6
20   0.0370   0.254    0.0927           1           9           1
```